# Declaring model with belongsTo not generating getter

Tags: extjs, model, extjs4

Based [on some examples](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/extjs-belongsto-association-rules.html) of `Ext.data.Model` with associations I wrote the following class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Children',{
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields : [{
    name: 'parent' //object of the belongsTo
  },{
    name: 'description',
    type: 'string'
  }],
  belongsTo : [{
    name: 'parent',
    foreignKey: 'parent', //also tried parent.id
    instanceName: 'parent',
    getterName: 'getParent',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Parent'
  }],
  proxy : {
    type: 'rest',
    url: '../rest/children',
    reader : {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'data'
    }
  }
});
```

Shouldn't this definition generate a `getChildren` method? The `MyApp.model.Parent` also have a proxy defined.

I'm testing with:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
  model: 'MyApp.model.Children'
});

store.load(function(recs){
  console.log(recs[0].getParent); //prints undefined instead of function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your parent model isn't loaded.  Try adding the `requires` configuration to your child model.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Children', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

   //ensures the Parent model is loaded first
   requires: 'MyApp.model.Parent',

   fields: ...
```